# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch in gae django project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am developing django non-rel gae project.

I am trying to use api. My code is as below:

```
FLOW = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
  CLIENT_SECRETS,
  scope=[RW_SCOPE, RO_SCOPE],
  redirect_uri='http://x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com/oauth2callback',
  message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS))
```

My project id is x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com. Though i am getting Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. In localhost it runs without error.

I found from stack overflow that i have to add(x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com) as redirect_uri. But as you can see in image there is two redirect_uris are set, So now how can i set (x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com) as redirect_uri?  I have no edit settings button on developer console.

[image]

Comment: In any case, the URL of your app is YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com, in your case, x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com (without a second .appspot.com)

Comment: Here my mistake in question. In my code i set redirect_uri as 'http://x2-single-odyssey-g.appspot.com/oauth2callback'.   So no problem related this. Please any other suggestion? I need it. THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

`redirect_uri` set for the flow object should match the one you set in the Developers Console -> Credentials. Failing to do that leads to the `redirect_uri_mismatch` you mentioned. You may also have a look at the web server flow example I provided at [1].

[1] - [Using OAuth2 on GAE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897189/using-oauth2-on-gae-in-python/25923156#25923156)